# filter array of object and add extra filed for duplicate value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a array of object. i want to filter by two key and if there is any duplicate item need to add extra key including details
for example

```
[
    {
        "start": 0,
        "end": 38,
        "content": "announcing improvements to the GitHub "
    },
    
    {
        "uuid": "6f08b9df-7b07-4da9-bbe0-8c93d5d0a19b",
        "start": 51,
        "end": 59,
        "entity_type": "class1",
        "content": "Workflow"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "21dffe1c-0f8c-4c13-8bee-6185fb15cbd8",
        "start": 51,
        "end": 59,
        "entity_type": "class2",
        "content": "Workflow"
    },
    {
        "start": 59,
        "end": 101,
        "content": "” experience. Now, when you want to create"
    }
]
```

and expected output is

```
let excepted = [
    {
        "start": 0,
        "end": 38,
        "content": "announcing improvements to the GitHub "
    },
    {
        "uuid": ["6f08b9df-7b07-4da9-bbe0-8c93d5d0a19b","21dffe1c-0f8c-4c13-8bee-6185fb15cbd8"],
        "start": 51,
        "end": 59,
        "isDuplicate":true,
        "labels":["class2","class1"],
        "content": "Workflow"
    },
    {
        "start_offset": 59,
        "end": 101,
        "content": "” experience. Now, when you want to create"
    }
]
```

in above example you can see for key start 51 and end 59 have two duplicate entry in output i want to aggregate both like in output labels

Comment: please add your code. what goes wrong?

Comment: Just search for [_"array of objects group by key"_](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+of+objects+group+by+key+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ia=web) here on SO and you will find plenty of questions and answers that will help you. They won't be a perfect match for your problem but with some minor adjustments you will get the solution you want.

Comment: Please show what you have done

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit different result, instead `"labels":["class2","class1"]` it's `"entity_type":["class2","class1"]`

```js
const arr = [{"start": 0,"end": 38,"content": "announcing improvements to the GitHub "},{"uuid": "6f08b9df-7b07-4da9-bbe0-8c93d5d0a19b","start": 51,"end": 59,"entity_type": "class1","content": "Workflow"},{"uuid": "21dffe1c-0f8c-4c13-8bee-6185fb15cbd8","start": 51,"end": 59,"entity_type": "class2","content": "Workflow"},{"start": 59,"end": 101,"content": "” experience. Now, when you want to create"}]
    
const reduced = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const hash = `${obj.start}-${obj.end}`;
  if (acc[hash]) {
    acc[hash] = {
      ...acc[hash],
      isDuplicate: true,
      uuid: Array.isArray(acc[hash].uuid) 
        ? [obj.uuid]
        : [acc[hash].uuid, obj.uuid],
      entity_type: Array.isArray(acc[hash].entity_type) 
        ? [obj.entity_type]
        : [acc[hash].entity_type, obj.entity_type],
    };
  } else {
    acc[hash] = { ...obj };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(reduced);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```